# Select every row with contains

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, freetext

I have a function that returns a table based on some filter. One of the filters is a title which can be null The following query is possible when filtering the table:

```
DECLARE @DocumentTitle VARCHAR(150)
SET @DocumentTitle = NULL
SELECT * 
FROM [table]
    WHERE   
    FREETEXT([Title], @DocumentTitle)
```

This means that the user doesn't want to filter the title. So I should set the `@DocumentTitle` a value that returns everything.

What is that value?

(I've already tried with '*', '""', '"*"', ' ', '').

OR

How I can make this work?

```
(@DocumentTitle IS NOT NULL AND FREETEXT([Title], @DocumentTitle))
```

because @DocumentTitle is null but it goes further to freetext.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
declare    @Search nvarchar(1000) = NULL --'test'
set    @Search = ISNULL(@Search , '""')

--if @Search is null returns everything
select    *
from    TestTabel
where    contains(Column, @Search ) OR @Search = '""'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could expand the where condition, doing something like this to make it work:

```
DECLARE @DocumentTitle VARCHAR(150)
SET @DocumentTitle = NULL
SELECT * 
FROM [table]
WHERE 
    FREETEXT([Title], @DocumentTitle)
        OR
    @DocumentTitle IS NULL
```